# Console window is not visible when output is redirected

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

I am using the following code from a .NET 4 console application:

```
private static void AttachToConsole ()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = null;

    process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Start();

    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Process_OutputDataReceived);

    Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    process.OutputDataReceived -= new DataReceivedEventHandler(Process_OutputDataReceived);
    process.CloseMainWindow();
    process.Close();
}
```

When run, only the console window of the app itself shows up but the `[cmd.exe]` process window remains invisible. Why is that and how can I change this behavior?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in LinqPad. I will see if it is present in a console application.

Comment: Do you update list of processes after run you cmd?

Comment: @Romoku: It may an issue with a console application.

Comment: @AndreyMaybe: Not sure what you mean but no, the code above is all there is.

Comment: All I can help is that I notices that when you change `Output type` from `Console application` to `Windows application` in project properties the second console will show

Comment: You already have a console window.  You don't get another one when you start cmd.exe, it uses yours.  You don't see anything because you redirect output.  And if you have .NET 4.5 installed, your Console.Read() call will prevent anything from being written when you use Console.Write() in your Process_OutputDataReceived() method.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you. I updated the code and shifted it to a WinForms application where it was eventually going to go anyways. Posted the new code in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094690/console-not-showing-redirected-data-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 2):

if you set `UseShellExecute = true` the cmd process window will appear. You wil need to set RedirectStandardInput and RedirectStandardpOutput to 'false' (or comment them out) however.

```
private static void AttachToConsole ()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = null;

    process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    //process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    //process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Start();

    process.OutputDataReceived += null;

    Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    process.OutputDataReceived -= null;
    process.CloseMainWindow();
    process.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do need to redirect the input.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know how to fix it but I know why it works like that.

You set

`UseShellExecute=false;`

well `cmd.exe` is `Windows Command Processor` so executing with windows shell creates new console windows which is terminal whose input is processed by the cmd.exe and output is directed to the terminal.

If you set `UseShellExecute=true` the window will show but you won't be able to redirect input and output and this is because of the way it works as I described in above paragraph

EDIT:
The most important part: you wrote "the process window"; console type procesesses have NO WINDOW at all